# Mysqldump with InnoDB tables, how to import them without errors?

Tags: mysql

I've exported a mysqldump of a database with InnoDB tables and foreign key relationships in them, using the --single-transaction flag (that I read somewhere I should use for InnoDB). No problems.

But when trying to import that dump into another existing database (same database, different server) I get all sorts of errors when trying to drop the tables because it would break the InnoDB relationships.

I also read that I should use  foreign_key_checks=0 to avoid this, but this is a server variable, not part of the dump process. So I'm trying to figure out how to automate all this since I have a script that backs up the DB, it was working when all we had were MyISAM tables:

mysqldump -u user -p'password' --single-transaction -q database | ssh user@backup.com mysql -u user -p'password' database

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the mysqldump file is smart enough to detect that they are InnoDB tables and puts the appropriate comments at the top of the file. My problem was that when I exported through PHPMyAdmin it didn't put the correct comments on the file, hence causing all this trouble.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

You can dump into a file, add the required `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in that file, and then feed the file to `mysql`.

Comment: So there's no way to do it from a mysqldupm is what you're saying? I'd have to create a script that does the dump, appends the foreign_key_checks=0 to the top of the dump, then foreign_key_checks=1 at the bottom and then sshs the dumped file to the backup server. Is that about it?

Comment: You can also play around with named pipes and/or clever uses of `cat` interposed between `mysqldump` and `mysql`... But no, `mysqldump` will not flip this one variable for you.

Comment: I found a solution like this: http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/141790-mysqldump-restore-innodb-tables helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add to the mysql command line when restoring without editing the original file. This is very useful as mysql backups can become huge, and editing a GB+ file takes lots of CPU time versus adding this to the commandline,

```
mysql -D YourDatabaseName -u YourUserName -p --init-command="set @@foreign_key_checks=0"<YourBackupDumpFile.sql
```